# How to remove overlapping rows based on date and keep most recent in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, overlapping

I need to find all episode_ids for every patient. However, when an overlapping episode arises within 90 days of the previous, then I just want to keep the most recent episode.

For example, `patient_num 3242` below has 3 episodes: the second episode overlaps with the first episode within 90 days, and the third episode overlaps with the second episode within 90 days, in this situation I need to just keep the 3rd episode.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (episode_id nvarchar(max), patient_num nvarchar(max), admit_date date,  discharge_date date)

INSERT INTO table1 (episode_id, patient_num , admit_date ,  discharge_date ) VALUES 
('1','5743','1/1/2016','1/5/2016'),
('2','5743','4/26/2016','4/29/2016'),
('3','5743','5/26/2016','5/28/2016'),
('4','5743','9/21/2016','9/28/2016'),
('5','8859','4/27/2016','5/5/2016'),
('6','3242','4/28/2016','4/29/2016'),
('7','3242','11/21/2016','11/23/2016'),
('8','3242','11/24/2016','11/29/2016'),
('9','3242','12/12/2016','12/29/2016')
```

Initial Table (table1)

```
episode_id   patient_num  admit_date   discharge_date
1            5743         2016-01-01   2016-01-05 
2            5743         2016-04-26   2016-04-29
3            5743         2016-05-26   2016-05-28
4            5743         2016-09-21   2016-09-28
5            8859         2016-04-27   2016-05-05
6            3242         2016-04-28   2016-04-29
7            3242         2016-11-21   2016-11-23
8            3242         2016-11-24   2016-11-29
9            3242         2016-12-12   2016-12-29
```

expected result

```
episode_id   patient_num  admit_date   discharge_date
1            5743         2016-01-01   2016-01-05 
3            5743         2016-05-26   2016-05-28
4            5743         2016-09-21   2016-09-28
5            8859         2016-04-27   2016-05-05
6            3242         2016-04-28   2016-04-29
9            3242         2016-12-12   2016-12-29
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS a
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 AS b
    WHERE      a.episode_id != b.episode_id
               AND a.patient_num= b.patient_num
               AND a.admit_date BETWEEN b.discharge_date AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, b.discharge_date ))
```

There error in my script is that for patient num `3242`, I am getting both episode id 8 and 9 where I only want episode 9. I am assuming the reason for this error is that I am comparing each row individually instead of as a group but I am having trouble grouping. Additionally, this script is not showing instances where there is not an overlap, such as the episode_id 1, 4, 5, 6. Any advice on this approach?

Comment: Give us the Script to generate the tables as you have them above

Comment: I added a script to generate the tables

Comment: As I see from data this is not correct:he second episode overlaps with the first episode within 90 days

Comment: The first and second episode are 112 days apart.

Comment: IMHO, we need to select all NON_Overlapped rows.  Then from the others create OverlapRanges and from within each OverlapRange select the TOP 1.  e.g. please clone episodes 7,8,9 and change their years to 2017.  The part I havent solved is creating the OverlapRange.  I am working with Celko-s definition of Overlap in SQL for Smarties which is slightly different from BETWEEN which includes the end points, whereas Overlap does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the cursor solution here since it has low perforamnce
a solution without using Cursor is:

```
WITH ExcludedIds AS (
SELECT DISTINCT T2.episode_id 
FROM table1  AS T 
INNER JOIN table1 AS T2 ON T.episode_id != T2.episode_id
               AND T.patient_num = T2.patient_num
               AND T2.discharge_date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -90, T.admit_date ) AND  T.discharge_date)

SELECT T.episode_id, T.patient_num, T.admit_date, T.discharge_date 
FROM table1 AS T 
WHERE T.episode_id NOT IN (SELECT ExcludedIds.episode_id FROM ExcludedIds)
```

Thought understanding this solution is a bit hard.

Comment: This can be solved using set-based logic.  A cursor is definitely not the right way to go.

Comment: How do you know that cursor is not efficient. Have you ever compared subquery performance against fast_forward readonly cursor. There is always a trade-off. It also depends on how many records the table has.

Comment: . . I have been working with relational databases since 1989.  And yes, at times in the past, I have compared performance.  I also understand how they work.

Comment: This is fantastic! I understand CTE better than cursors so plus 1 for that! Also, your CTE answer takes about 10 min while the cursor took about 2 hours.

Comment: I am Happy that it helped. I think @GordonLinoff deserves up-vote for his comment not his solution.

Comment: create an index for these four fields and the query will run less than 1 min: episode_id, patient_num , admit_date ,  discharge_date

Answer (score -1):

I think `not exists` does what you want:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table1 b
                  WHERE a.episode_id <> b.episode_id AND
                        a.patient_num = b.patient_num AND
                        b.admin_date < a.discharge_date AND
                        b.discharge_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, a.discharge_date)
                 );
```

Comment: your query returns all the 9 records. First thing in writing a good query is that it must be correct. efficiency comes next.

Comment: I did down-vote your code not you and it is because your answer is wrong. Why do you think it is rude? Please do not consider it personal. I think down-vote shows others to not concentrate on an answer.